# VBA String search using Like and wildcard

Tags: excel, vba

I am doing a pattern search using the `Like` operator. This is what I came up with so far:

```
if MyString Like "*sometext?" + "_*" then
    debug.print "Match found!" 
else
    debug.print "Not a match"
```

I need this to match only if the character between `sometext` and `_` is a digit (only one single digit, no alphanumeric). For example:

`MyString='testingsometext3_whatever'` should be a match,

`MyString='testingsometext321_whatever'` should not be a match (there are 3 digits, not just a single one)

`MyString='testingsometext_whatever'` should not be be a match, as there is no character between `text` and `_`

`MyString='testingsometexts_whatever'` should not be be a match (there is at least one alphanumeric between `text` and `_`) - T*his is what is not working for me at the moment and I need help with*

Comment: reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator) tells you `?` is the pattern for any single character, whereas `#` is the pattern for any single digit

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad though [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/like-operator) is the VBA doc page - that's VB.Net. Same idea though.

Comment: Side note. Use `&` to concatenate, not `+`. Though you don't need to concatenate at all: `"*sometext#_*"`.

Comment: @BigBen - quite right, I used the wrong bookmark :(

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad it is impossible to find the documentation sometimes. Google almost always interprets VBA as VB...

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad - yours is the most straightforward answer, given the code already in place; I will accept it as "the" answer, if you post it as such

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since OP seems to think it is the most straightforward answer:

```
if MyString Like "*sometext#_*" then
    debug.print "Match found!" 
else
    debug.print "Not a match"
end if
```

[Link to the relevant documentation (courtesy of BigBen)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/like-operator)

Answer (score 7):

While Regular Expressions is probably overkill, I find it easier to use.

Try the following code:

```
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Pattern = "testingsometext\d_whatever"
    If .Test(MyString) Then
        debug.print "Match found!" 
    else
        debug.print "Not a match"
    End If
End With
```

## Breaking Down the Pattern

This pattern is actually pretty simple.

- `testingsometext` is matching the literal string
- `\d` matches any single digit
- `_whatever` is matching a literal string

---

### IMPORTANT To keep in mind!

This will match `blahtestingsometext1_whateverblah` as well, because there are no start/end of string anchors.

I went this route for you because you placed asterisks on both ends of your pattern (`*sometext?_*`) and assumed that this was desired. If this is not the desired behavior and only want to match the exact phrase with nothing before or after the string, then change the the pattern line to:
`.Pattern = "^testingsometext\d_whatever$"`.

Comment: If not easier to use, definitely more flexible and portable.

Comment: this is the most professional answer; upvoted, but a tiny-bitoverkill considering the code is already in place (and the beginner level of the coder ;))

Answer (score 0):

Something like so in VBA

```
Sub test_teststring()

Debug.Print TESTSTRING("testingsometext3_whatever")
Debug.Print TESTSTRING("testingsometext13_whatever")
Debug.Print TESTSTRING("testingsometext113_whatever")
Debug.Print TESTSTRING("testingsometext_whatever")

End Sub

Function TESTSTRING(strInput As String) as Boolean

Dim s() As String

s = Split(strInput, "_")

TESTSTRING = IsNumeric(Right(s(0), 1)) And Not IsNumeric(Right(s(0), 2))

End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

```
If IsNumeric(Mid(MyString, InStr(MyString, "_") - 1, 1)) And _
        Not IsNumeric(Mid(MyString, InStr(MyString, "_") - 2, 1)) Then
    Debug.Print "Match found!"
 Else
    Debug.Print "Not a match"
 End If
```

Comment: I removed my DV.